# I need help with my minecraft skin

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been trying to use my Minecraft custom made skin i have used it in singleplayer and multiplayer working and lately I have been playing singleplayer no problem but when i play multiplayer i don't see my skin but other people do and yes i have bought minecraft

this is my skin just in case there is a problem with it:

[image: Minecraft Skin]

Comment: Have you restarted your game after you uploaded your skin?

Comment: Try replacing the `char.png` file. Then you should be able see your skin.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms that shall make everybody with a Steve skin that skin.

Comment: where do i replace it and replace it for what

Comment: and i have restarted my minecraft

Answer (score 0):

You need to be on the exact same version as the server.. Example: servers version is 1.7.9 you need to be on 1.7.9 it's a problem with bukkit

Comment: nonono, that's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're using your skin as part of a custom resource pack (i.e. creating a folder named mobs, then placing your skin inside and naming it char.png), it won't sync with the Minecraft website. Go to https://minecraft.net/profile and upload your skin to sync it with the website, which will allow you to see your skin on servers.

Hope this helps. (Otherwise, it could be a server-side error, like Taco said in the other answer)